# "Service Account" User in AWS Cognito For Backend Applications

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

Our application uses API Gateway (backed by dotnet AWS Lambda Functions).  We use cognito to authenticate and authorize the web users.  No problem.

This is for a multitenant application.

We have lambda functions that run business processes in the back end.

I'd like to use a cognito based user for each tenant to "authenticate" the process running in order to filter the data for each tenant.

Is there some concept of a "service account" from Cognito that I can apply here?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but not straight forward like what you have in any other case.

- One way is you can create an IAM user with necessary permissions and
  policies who can access to cognito and your applications.
- You can access the backend using this IAM user credentials.

Comment: Thanks, but that's way too powerful, the lambda functions already has an IAM Role.  Plus, I don't want to add a new IAM user for each tenant.